# Redirect /en (or /default) to root in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url, redirect

Edit:

I have a multilingual website in Magento with 4 language codes: en, de, fr, es. The default language is en and therefore the URL is myexample.com/en, but the problem is that due to indexing issues, it has to be redirected with 301s to myexample.com/

**Just to clarify: My Magento installation *is not* in a subdirectory, it's on the root of the server.**

I've been trying different combinations for the .htaccess file, and one of them sort of works but not totally, because it only redirects myexample.com/en to myexample.com and I need to redirect also all the CMS pages, products and categories within /en to /

The code is:

```
RewriteRule (^[a-z0-9\-]+)\.html /en/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (^catalog/.*) /en/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule en/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, to sum it up, what I want to achieve is:

1. myexample.com/en redirected to myexample.com because it's the default language.
2. All the content, CMS pages, products and categories within /en redirected to / , so instead of myexample.com/en/faqs it would be myexample.com/faqs and instead of myexample.com/en/shop it will be myexample.com/shop.
3. All the other language codes have to stay the same, so it will be myexample.com/es, myexample.com/de and myexample.com/fr with all their associated CMS pages, products and categories.

Any ideas on what is wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^en/ /%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Check the [link](http://husseycoding.blogspot.in/2013/01/installing-magento-in-subdirectory.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code but that's totally the opposite of what I want to do. As I said on my question, I want myexample.com/en redirected to myexample.com/ and not the other way. Also, the link provided isn't valid for my scenario, because Magento isn't installed in a subdirectory, it's installed in the root of the server.